# Updating serialzed ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arraylist, serialization, deserialization, binary-data

I am making a project where I need to save data to binary file using serilazation. I know how to read and write parameterized ArrayList using *ObjectInputStream*, *ObjectOutputStream* and *FileInputStream*. However I have no idea how I would go about updating ArrayList when new value is added or deleted.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class testSerialization {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String fileName = "test.bin";
        ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
        // Insert sample data
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
            integers.add(i);
        }
        try{
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
            oos.writeObject(integers);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        try {
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
            ArrayList<Integer> ps = (ArrayList<Integer>) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println(ps);
            ois.close();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

One way I can do it is that I just override all the data with updated data everytime I get a change, but there is probably better alternative solution

Comment: It sounds like you want to be editing your list in your program, and serialize it with every edit. Depending on how much/how fast you change your list though, it might be better to serialize it every few minutes (or on whatever time interval) instead of on every edit though. What are you using this for?

Comment: The better alternative solution is not to use serialization for this but rather a database. Serialization is for keeping whole objects.

Comment: @FlexEast I'll probably make it with serializing it with every change because I don't really need the speed since I'm making this for GUI application and the change is made one at the time by the user

Comment: @RealSkeptic I know but sadly the project requirements are that we use serialization